# MySQL: select the not-empty value from joined tables with the same column name

Tags: mysql, join

In my database structure I have two tables with some columns that contain the same name.
For this example I have the table `products` and `products_options`. Both tables have the column `sku`.

It is possible that the column is filled in both tables or in one of either tables.
I was wondering if it is possible to add something to the `SELECT` part of the query to select the SKU as following:

- If `sku` is empty in `products_options` and not empty in `products`: return the value of `products`
- If `sku` is not empty in `products_options` and not empty in `products`: return the value of `products_options`
- If `sku` is not empty in `products_options` and empty in `products`: return the value of `products_options`

Is something like this possible in MySQL?

Comment: Please show what you have so far. How are the tables joined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try `coalesce()` function like this :

```
select coalesce(p1.sku,p2.sku) as sku
from(
    (select id,sku from products_option) as p1
    inner join
    (select id,sku from products) as p2
    on p1.id = p2.id
)
```

Comment: Why the subqueries? Are you sure about the INNER JOIN?

Comment: That's the function I was looking for, thank you! The subqueries aren't necessary in this situation, I'm already joining the tables.